# Need to relationalise a nested JSON string using Pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, nested

I am new to **Pyspark** and need guidance to perform the following task.
A `sample` data in the form of a JSON string has been given,

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "location": "znd",
   "contact": "{\"phone\": [{\"number\":\"12345\",\"code\":\"111\",\"altno\":\"No\"},{\"number\":\"55656\",\"code\":\"222\",\"altno\":\"Yes\"}]}"
```

}

This needs to be `rationalized` as follows, as seen below one row of input will get translated to 2 rows.

```
{id: "1234", "location": "znd","number": "12345", "code": "111","altno":"No"} 

{id: "1234", "location": "znd","number": "55656", "code": "222","altno":"No"}
```

I have tried to use the `explode function` but as this is a JSON string, explode does not work on it.

I have read the data into a `DF` and tried to enforce a struct type to later use `explode`, but that does not work either.

Comment: I think your json string is not formatted correctly, could you provide a reproducible example in the form of a dataframe column? it would help others answer too.

Comment: Updated the JSON string.